# Windows Server Backup not working on scheduled task but working with the "Backup Once"

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012, command-line-interface, windows-server-backup, wbadmin

I'm trying to create Backup Schedule from my local drive on a network share but Windows Server 2012 won't let me. I get the error "The parameters are incorrect". When I try the "Backup Once" with all the same settings it just works...

After a few search on the internet, I've found that the Backup Schedule needs to run using the local administrator user. Then I found the backup schedule is using "wbadmin" and that it would use the "Volume Shadow Copy" local service so I tried to edit that service to "Log on" as a local admin but no luck (it's even worst because it fail faster with the same error).

So I tried to find another solution which was to open a terminal and manually try the wbadmin command line (without the Windows Backup Server GUI) so it could run with the administrator user, and then add a scheduled task with the local administrator etc (sounds fair).

BUT, when I open the command line and try to do this command, it just fail saying I get a `command syntax incorrect. Error: -addtarget:\\NAS\Backup:`

```
wbadmin enable backup –addtarget:\\NAS\Backup –include:c:\TestBackup –user:\OutsideDomainUser –password:MyPassword –schedule:22:00
```

I'm pretty sure the command is OK as I got it directly from the Microsoft doc right here (it's Senario #2):
[Wbadmin enable backup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742130.aspx)

Can someone help me to make the GUI or the wbadmin command to work correctly using a network share as destination.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct.

Assuming the target you want to add is reachable, then this error message concerns any of the previously added targets. Check the targets using:

```
wbadmin get disks
```

and make them available or remove them (`-removetarget`)

Look here for ["Error message when you try to add an additional disk to a scheduled backup ..." by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2009365/error-message-when-you-try-to-add-an-additional-disk-to-a-scheduled-ba).